# Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'iterator' was called on null

Tags: json, flutter, api

#this is my model class

```
 class Student {
  Student({
    this.stname,
    this.rollno,
    this.regno,
    this.homeworkStatus,
    this.replies,
  });

  String stname;
  int rollno;
  String regno;
  HomeworkStatus homeworkStatus;
  List<Reply> replies;

  factory Student.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Student(
    stname: json["STNAME"],
    rollno: json["ROLLNO"],
    regno: json["REGNO"],
    homeworkStatus:json["homeworkStatus"].toString()==null?"pending":homeworkStatusValues.map[json["homeworkStatus"]],
    replies: json['replies'].toString()!=null?List<Reply>.from(json["replies"]?.map((x)=>Reply.fromJson(x))):" ", //i am getting error in this place
    // replies:List<Reply>.from(json["replies"])==null?"pending":List<Reply>.from(json["replies"]?.map((x) => Reply.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "STNAME": stname,
    "ROLLNO": rollno,
    "REGNO": regno,
    "homeworkStatus": homeworkStatusValues.reverse[homeworkStatus],
    "replies":replies!=null?List<dynamic>.from(replies.map((x) => x.toJson())):" ",
  };
}
```

#error says  Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'iterator' was called on null. Receiver: null, Tried calling: iterator

#the thing is this is how my json data comes ar first

```
 "students": [
        {
            "STNAME": "Name 1",
            "ROLLNO": 2,
            "REGNO": "ST077777"
        },
        {
            "STNAME": "Name 2",
            "ROLLNO": 5,
            "REGNO": "ST077000"
        },
]
```

#and after one student give replies then above json changes to this format

```
     "students": [
            {
                "STNAME": "name 1",
                "ROLLNO": 1,
                "REGNO": "ST072000",
                "homeworkStatus": "completed",
                "replies": [
                    {
                        "comments": "sdfsdf",
                        "id": 42552325,
                        "schoolid": "CSsdfds",
                        "filenames": "asdasd.jpg",
                        "homework_id": 14545,
                        "filelinks": "gfdgdf.jpg",
                        "fileUniquenames": "fsasf.jpg",
                        "homework_status": "completed",
                        "regno": "45456",
                        "teacher_id": null,
                        "reply_from": "student",
                        "status": "completed",
                        "created_at": "2022-01-03 12:05:30"
                    },
]
]
```

#the homeworkstatus and replies key doesnt exist at first and it exists only after one student give replies to that homework and i am having error when i am trying to fetch the list of student name and homeworkstatus but at first the key homeworkstatus and replies doesnt exist so i am getting this error error says  Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'iterator' was called on null. Receiver: null, Tried calling: iterator. need your guidance the error directly points to my model class i have written in which specific code also . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may remove toString() from these two lines:

```dart
homeworkStatus:json["homeworkStatus"].toString()==null?"pending":homeworkStatusValues.map[json["homeworkStatus"]],
replies: json['replies'].toString()!=null?List<Reply>.from(json["replies"]?.map((x)=>Reply.fromJson(x))):" ",
```

To:

```dart
homeworkStatus:json["homeworkStatus"] == null ? "pending" : homeworkStatusValues.map[json["homeworkStatus"]],
replies: json['replies'] != null ? List<Reply>.from(json["replies"]?.map((x)=>Reply.fromJson(x))) : null,
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but it didnt work but i work it around